# Optimising GPU use for Keras model training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I'm training a Keras model. During the training, I'm only utilising between 5 and 20% of my CUDA cores and an equally small proportion of my **NVIDIA RTX 2070** memory. Model training is pretty slow currently and I would really like to take advantage of as many of my available CUDA cores as possible to speed this up!

`nvidia dmon # (during model training)`

```
# gpu   pwr gtemp mtemp    sm   mem   enc   dec  mclk  pclk
# Idx     W     C     C     %     %     %     %   MHz   MHz
    0    45    49     -     9     6     0     0  6801  1605
```

What parameters should I look to tune in order to increase CUDA core utilisation with the aim of training the same model faster?

Here's a simplified example of my current image generation and training steps (I can elaborate / edit, if required, but I currently believe these are the key steps for the purpose of the question):

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'./input_training_examples',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary'
)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'./input_validation_examples',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary'
)

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=128, epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=50,
)
```

Hardware: *NVIDIA 2070 GPU*

Platform: *Linux 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu x86_64, NVIDIA driver 440.64, CUDA 10.2, Tensorflow 2.2.0-rc3*

Answer (score 2):

GPU utilization is a tricky business, there are too many factors involved.

The first thing to try obviously: **increase batch size**.

But that solely doesn't ensure the max utilization, maybe your I/O is slow so there is a bottleneck in the data_generator.

You can try loading the full data as a `NumPy` array if you have enough ram memory.

You can try increasing number of workers in multiprocessing scheme.

`model.fit(..., use_multiprocessing=True, workers=8)`

Finally, depends on your model, if your model is too light and not deep, your utilization will be low and there's no standard way to improve it any further.